# What is the meaning of 'photo[name]' in HTML form?

Tags: html, node.js, file, upload

I know this is a silly question but I really dont understand what the meaning of 'photo[name]' in this HTML form is. Here is the object I received and there is 'photo[name]' too, so is it better if I just replace 'photo[name]' with something like 'myphoto'?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Upload a photo to your account below.</p>
    <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <p><input
                type='text', name='photo[name]', placeholder='Name' /></p>
      <p><input type='file', name='photo[image]' /></p>
      <p><input type='submit', value='Upload' /></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the name of the field where you should input the name of you photo (not the file itself), it can be something like "My new house". 
In the HTML you have a text field `photo[name]`, so this is what you got.
You are free to rename it, but you should rename it everywhere it appears in your file.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a name of a field or an id of an html (DOM) object.  I think you are reading too much into the square brackets and the fact that it looks like an array access. "photo[name]" is just as valid as your suggestion of "myphoto" in this context.

As an example, in the case of the `id` attribute in HTML5:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

> There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.